# ReactJs error in dynamic routing when two routes have similar credentials

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

Please note that I am using react-router-dom and not react-router

As you can see from my routes, When I enter the route "/usermanager/Edit/1", instead of redirecting me to the EditEmployee.js component, it is redirecting me the SingleEmployee.js component and considers the word "Edit" in the route as an Id, which of course is causing a tremendous amount of errors. How do I solve this issue?

See the image below of what happens. I console.logged the id from the SingleEmpolyee.js Component

[image: Error]

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/Login" > <Login /> </Route>
    <Route exact path="/usermanager"> <Protected Cmp={ViewAllUsers} />  </Route>
    <Route exaxt path={"/usermanager/:id"}> <Protected Cmp={SingleEmployee} /></Route>
    <Route exaxt path={"/usermanager/Edit/:id"}> <Protected Cmp={EditEmployee} /></Route>
    <Redirect exact from="/" to="/Login" />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: You mean Edit is Id and ":id" is also id ??

Comment: @RanuVijay I will update my question to answer yours. But only the word edit is taken as an id

Comment: put the route containing id above the route without id. This would solve your case.

Comment: both contain Id. the route /edit/id is used to edit the user with this id

Comment: @RanuVijay Actually switching the two routes really did solve the problem, but is this a proper solution. If my routing technique is wrong can you please suggest a thread or tutorial as an answer so that I can accept it. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Because :id is not the proper URL so your routes match the first.  Well, I came across the same issue so I know, your can search for a thread or tutorial on google.

Comment: You have 2 typos exaxt, the route  <Route path={"/usermanager/Edit/:id"}> <Protected Cmp={EditEmployee} /> must be defined in ViewAllUsers